# GetListAdapter() in ListFragment returns null

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

Im trying to update the List in a ListFragment, but whenever i use functions like `clear()` or `addAll()` the returned adapter from `getListAdapter()` is null.

I can successfully get the new Data from a different Fragment. in MainActivity, once new Data has been received from an interface, I call the Method **UpdatePlaylist()** inside my ListFragment from MainActivity. So Im updating the content inside of the ListFragment itself.

**ListFragment:**

```
public class PlaylistMusicBox extends ListFragment{

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    List<String> Playlist = Arrays.asList("Loading Songs...");

    public PlaylistMusicBox() {
    }

    public static PlaylistMusicBox newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaylistMusicBox fragment = new PlaylistMusicBox();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.song_list, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Playlist);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void UpdatePlaylist(List<String> NewPlaylist){

        if (NewPlaylist!=null) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) getListAdapter();
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.clear();
            adapter.addAll(NewPlaylist);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } else {
            System.out.println("New PLaylist is null");
        }
    }

}
```

I get the Error Message:  `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.clear()' on a null object reference`, but my Adapter is defined in onCreateActivity so I don't understand why null is returned as the adapter.

I also tried just setting the Adapter again, with the newly obtained list, but I still get the Error that my Context is null...How can I update Data in the ListFragment?

Comment: why are you doing this ?  "  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) getListAdapter();
            setListAdapter(adapter); "

Comment: I defined my Adapter inside of `OnViewCreated`, so its only available inside `OnViewCreated`. I tried setting the Adapter at the beginning of my ListFragment like `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;`, so that i can just call adapter without `getListAdapter()`, but I got the same Error. I thought it would be safer to get the adapter with `getListAdapter`, because then I know for sure that it has been created, and then set it again. Don't really know if that is even needed though.

Comment: But how can I then change the List in the ListFragment later, when i can't set the adapter again?